# What is {} used for in this context?

Tags: bash

It is doing something to my path_bash variable but what?

Google pulls up [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html) but I can't find it exactly.

```
#!/bin/bash

path_bash="$HOME/root/config/bash/"
source "${path_bash}_private.sh"
source "${path_bash}config.sh"
source "${path_bash}utility.sh"
source "${path_bash}workflow.sh"
source "${path_bash}net.sh"
source "${path_bash}makeHTM.sh"
```

and can I put

```
path_bash
```

in another file?

Comment: As an aside, if you had `source "$path_bash/_private.sh"`, then you'd no longer need the curly braces, because the immediate next character would be something that couldn't be used in a variable name -- and you'd *also* be robust against the case where `path_bash` didn't have a trailing slash.

Comment: BTW, re: the links given you by Google, TLDP has a lot of Google juice, but their "Advanced" Bash Guide also has a reputation for showcasing bad practices and being only rarely updated. You're better off using either [the Wooledge BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) or [the bash-hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/), or of course [the official documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/).

Answer (score 4):

It's used to tell bash where the name of your variable ends.

And example to explain:

```
$ a="gg"
$ echo $ab

$ echo ${a}b
ggb
```

Comment: So in general I can put it around any variable? Also where is this in the documentation?

Comment: You can find it under "shell parameter expansion" https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: Technically, `${a}` is the canonical way to perform parameter expansion. The braces can be optionally (and typically are) dropped when no parameter expansion operators are used and the name of the variable can be unambiguously determined.